# Problems with loading local html pages in android 4+

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a problem with loading local html pages to webView in android 4. Before, I tested it for android 2.3 and it was ok. I load the page like this webView.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/drawable/test.html) I read a lot of information about bug with loading local pages, but I have not solution of this problem. Can you explain me why it doesn't load pages and write that "Web page not avaliable" . May be problems with "file:///" or "android_asset". Please give me real advice how I can load my html pages to webview in android 4. I really need. Thank you.

P.S I am sure that the file exists in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I used:

```
private final int boundaryApiValue = 10; 

/**Function set root directory for current api version.*/ 

    private void setRootPathForCurrentVersionOfAndroid() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= boundaryApiValue)
            rootPath = "file:///android_res/drawable/";
        else {
            rootPath = "file:///android_asset/res/drawable/";
        }
    }
```

If u have a version lower than Android HoneyComb than u should load html files for webview from "file:///android_asset/res/drawable/" if u have HoneyComb and later than use "file:///android_res/drawable/" It's works for me fine.